# key error not in index while cross validation

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have applied svm on my dataset. my dataset is multi-label means each observation has more than one label.

while `KFold cross-validation` it raises an error `not in index`.

It shows the index from 601 to 6007 `not in index` (I have 1...6008 data samples).

This is my code:

```py
   df = pd.read_csv("finalupdatedothers.csv")
categories = ['ADR','WD','EF','INF','SSI','DI','others']
X= df[['sentences']]
y = df[['ADR','WD','EF','INF','SSI','DI','others']]
kf = KFold(n_splits=10)
kf.get_n_splits(X)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

SVC_pipeline = Pipeline([
                ('tfidf', TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)),
                ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(), n_jobs=1)),
            ])

for category in categories:
    print('... Processing {} '.format(category))
    # train the model using X_dtm & y
    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train['sentences'], y_train[category])

    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(X_test['sentences'])
    print('SVM Linear Test accuracy is {} '.format(accuracy_score(X_test[category], prediction)))
    print 'SVM Linear f1 measurement is {} '.format(f1_score(X_test[category], prediction, average='weighted'))
    print([{X_test[i]: categories[prediction[i]]} for i in range(len(list(prediction)))])
```

Actually, I do not know how to apply KFold cross-validation in which I can get the F1 score and accuracy of each label separately.
having looked at [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.KFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.KFold) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16379313/how-to-use-the-a-k-fold-cross-validation-in-scikit-with-naive-bayes-classifier-a) did not help me how can I successfully to apply on my case.

**for being reproducible, this is a small sample of the data frame**
the last seven features are my labels including ADR, WD,...

```
,sentences,ADR,WD,EF,INF,SSI,DI,others
0,"extreme weight gain, short-term memory loss, hair loss.",1,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,I am detoxing from Lexapro now.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
2,I slowly cut my dosage over several months and took vitamin supplements to help.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
3,I am now 10 days completely off and OMG is it rough.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
4,"I have flu-like symptoms, dizziness, major mood swings, lots of anxiety, tiredness.",0,1,0,0,0,0,0
5,I have no idea when this will end.,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

**Update**

when I did whatever Vivek Kumar said It raises the error

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 5408]
```

in classifier part . do you have any idea how to resolve it?

there are a couple of links for this error in stackoverflow which says I need to reshape training data. I also did that but no success [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379200/valueerror-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-6-1786)
Thanks :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? you wrote that when using KFold you get an error. is this in the code you attached? on what line

Comment: @ShaharA Thanks for the comment. it raises error when it want to do KFold. so early line in the code, the reason I put the whole code here is that to show what purpose later I want to use them. Actually the code working perfectly when I apply train_test_split, but with KFOLD it does not

Comment: Did you try kf.split(X) without the y inside?

Comment: @ShaharA Yes Actually, it seems it does not relate to that argument

Comment: I also updated with a small sample of my data frame so it is now reproducible.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`train_index`, `test_index` are integer indices based on the number of rows. But pandas indexing dont work like that. Newer versions of pandas are more strict in how you slice or select data from them.

You need to use `.iloc` to access the data. More information is [available here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position)

This is what you need:

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X,y):
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_index], X.iloc[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_index], y.iloc[test_index]

    ...
    ...

    # TfidfVectorizer dont work with DataFrame, 
    # because iterating a DataFrame gives the column names, not the actual data
    # So specify explicitly the column name, to get the sentences

    SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train['sentences'], y_train[category])

    prediction = SVC_pipeline.predict(X_test['sentences'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, then how can I figure out when passing training to the classifier? with this I got this error: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 5408] at this line SVC_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train[category]). thanks for taking the time

Comment: Again thanks, Actually I have also tried this way but it raises error:

Comment: File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'ADR'

Comment: even X_train and y_train is kind of yellow shows there is something wrong with them but im not able to figure it out . I also saw this post of you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429600/indexing-a-csv-running-into-inconsistent-number-of-samples-for-logistic-regressi but it did not help :|

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi On your sample data and code you provided in the question above, I am not getting this error. Please update the question with the current complete code (that you used after taking hints from this answer) and also the complete stack trace of error.

Comment: Thats too weird actually, I again copy pasted the whole code I have, and the data frame is really the same

Comment: I also copy paste the first 5 rows of my data. the weird thing is that even before running the code X_train['sentences'], y_train in fitting is already yellow shows something wrong.

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi You added a new line in there: `print([{X_test[i]: categories[prediction[i]]} for i in range(len(list(prediction)))])`. The error is from this. X_train and X_test are dataframes, indexing dont work on them like you want.

Comment: Oh sorry I did not realize that might be a problem as in the error it point out to print('SVM Linear Test accuracy is {} '.format(accuracy_score(X_test[category], prediction))) . I have no idea what is my option if i can not use indexing test_x[i]. may I ask you please help with this part also . sorry I know its not part of this question

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi Use iloc.  `print([(X_test['sentences'].iloc[i], categories[prediction[i]]) for i in range(len(list(prediction)))])`

Comment: raises error :| should not I change the accuracy _score part also?

Comment: @sariaGoudarzi Yes. Replace `X_test[category]` with `y_test[category]` in both lines.

Comment: I just figured it out right now, my mistake this one so sorry for that, greatly appreciate your help and patience. best of luck :)